# How to activate Nvidia settings - fan control?

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, fancontrol, nvidia-settings, nvidia-geforce

After upgrading 14.10=>15.04 (Kubuntu), some defaults disappeared. Archived Xorg.conf, etc. Reactivated fan control using "Option "CoolBits" "4""

So now, in the NV-Control (Nvidia X Server Settings app) in the Thermal Sensor Information section, it appears but is inactive (greyed out). Yes, I have tried starting it with "kdesudo", "kdesu", "gksu", "sudo", etc.

How to make active please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! The checkboxes are not rendering. Click in the vicinity where you think the checkbox would be and it will. Probably the default theme in Kubuntu 15.04.

[image]